# How do I solve this error: Unable to load requested publish tab file: tab.tag.php

Tags: solspace-tag

I just upgraded from EE 2 to EE 3 and in the process removed Solspace Tag from the configuration by uninstalling it in EE 2.

Now however while running EE 3.5.7, when I try to edit any entries in the control panel I get the following error:

> Error: Unable to load requested publish tab file: tab.tag.php

Since I no longer need Solspace Tag I need to know how to resolve this issue without having to purchase the add-on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you completely uninstall Tag while in EE2? It sounds like you may not have. If you need a copy of Tag 5.x for EE3 to quickly uninstall Tag, just contact our support. :)

https://solspace.com/expressionengine/create-ticket/tag

Comment: At this point, all I can say is that if I didn't completely uninstall Tag while in EE2, I had the best of intentions. I contacted support as suggested. Thanks.